# SQL Server 2005 Querying XML column Data

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

I have a table called `People` with a columns of datatype `xml` called `properties`. I've used this to store random information about each person basically allowing people to store any extra data that are added in the future without a database redesign. Not all people will have the same elements in their xml.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
 [PersonID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [PersonType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Title] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
 [Forename] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
 [Surname] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
 [Company] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
 [Properties] [xml] NULL
)
```

An example of the xml is:

```
<PropertyList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Property Name="Class">Class A</Property>
  <Property Name="CarRegistration">123456</Property>
  <Property Name="MedicalNotes">None</Property>
</PropertyList>
```

First question is I can't seem to find a SQL query that will allow me to get a list of records that match criteria stored in the xml.

For example how would i get all records where the `Class="Class A"`. I've tried :

```
SELECT 
    PersonID, 
    Properties.value('/PropertyList/Property[@Name="Class"][1]','nvarchar(50)') 
FROM Person
```

I know this is incorrect but I get the error "requires a singleton (or empty sequence)" and I'm not quite sure whats gone wrong.

And second side question is I've combined several older databases into a single person list however the old database frontends still need to access their bit of the data. My plan was to create a view for each database frontend with a layout specific for its needs all linking back to the main people table. However some of their fields are now stored in the XML. Is there any way of creating a view to update the XML without seeing the xml i.e. so it looks and acts just like a view on any other table. I hope i explained that correctly. For each view I will have a specific set of XML properties I need them to edit and all records will have them so its not so random.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your XQuery should be:

```
SELECT PersonID, 
       Properties.value('(/PropertyList/Property[@Name="Class"])[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') 
FROM dbo.Person
```

Does that help??

*Update:* to make it clearer for others - I've added parenthesis around the `/PropertyList/Property[@Name="Class"]` expression, so that this will evaluate to potentially a list of values, and then the `[1]` after the parenthesis will select the first (and most often only) value (as a singleton) of that list so it can be converted to a `NVARCHAR(50)` string.

```
value('(/PropertyList/Property[@Name="Class"])[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') 
       !                                     !
```

is **NOT** the same as

```
value('/PropertyList/Property[@Name="Class"][1]','NVARCHAR(50)')
```

**Update 2:** if you want to create a view - sure, no reason not to! ;-)

You could definitely create something like:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourViewName
AS
    SELECT
        PersonID, PersonType, Title, 
        ForeName, Surname, Company,
        Properties.value('(/PropertyList/Property[@Name="Class"])[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS 'Class',
        Properties.value('(/PropertyList/Property[@Name="CarRegistration"])[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS 'CarRegistration',
        Properties.value('(/PropertyList/Property[@Name="MedicalNotes"])[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS 'MedicalNotes'
```

from your table and "break up" the XML into columns on your view. Is that what you're looking for??

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko: **NO!!** I added parenthesis to the XQuery expression (which are essential in this case!) Without the parenthesis (original post), it doesn't work and gives an error - with my parenthesis, it works - check closely!!

Comment: @marc_s: can you explain why the parens should make a difference? Sure, in theory, if a Properties column value could be an XML document fragment with multiple /PropertyList elements, then the parens would mean the difference between "the first Property named Class" and "the first Property named Class of each PropertyList". But assuming each Properties column value has only one /PropertyList element, there's no difference, right? In fact in his example, there's only one Property named "Class" so the `[1]` shouldn't make a difference at all.

Comment: @LarsH: as far as I understand, the XPath inside the parens basically returns a **list of nodes** - often just a single one, but it's no less a list. Using the [1] defines that you're interested in the first element of that list. Using `/text()` on that list just concatenates together the textual representation of the nodes. But since the XPath always returns a list and the `.value()` function only expects a single object, you need the [1] - whether or not that XPath returns just a single node or not.

Comment: Excellent it does indeed work with parenthesis inserted. Tnx. Any comments on my question regarding a view to display a table of the xml properties?

Comment: @marc_s: It worked, so I guess you're right. However there's nothing in XPath itself that changes the value of an XPath expression from a single-node list to a mere element, just by selecting only one node of the list. By appending "[1]", you still end up with a list (with at most one node in it). The "[1]" should only make a difference if (a) the pattern without the "[1]" selected more than one node (which I can't see how that's possible); or (b) SQL Server does something "special" about recognizing the presence of "[1]" and therefore accepts the single-node nodelist returned by XPath.

Comment: @marc_s: using "expression/text()" selects all the text node children of elements selected by "expression". It does not in itself concatenate anything. However `string(nodelist)` concatenates the contents of the text node descendants of the first node in `nodelist`. (I'm speaking of standard XPath 1.0 here... in ignorance of what SQL Server may do differently with its implementation of XPath.)

Comment: @marc_s: I see now. "The following query on an untyped XML column requires an ordinal specification on //author/last-name since the value() method expects a Singleton node as the first argument. Without it, the compiler cannot determine whether only one <last-name> node will occur at run time." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28SQL.90%29.aspx) So (b) above was correct... the SQL Server XPath/XQuery compiler needs the [1] in some cases to guarantee that the expression will always return a list of only one node. Thanks for answering my curiosity. :-)